# VPN connection breaks internet

Tags: 10.10, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

After installing OpenVPN properly (`network-manager-openvpn`) and setting up my VPN, I am not able to connect to any internet page or access anything that's remote. Pinging stuff is totally dead.

I have absolutely no idea on how to proceed from now. What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's perfectly normal, as by default, all connections are made through your VPN. You have two options:

- you can configure you VPN server to let connections to the outside go through the VPN
- you can configure you client to only use your VPN for connections to other machines in the private network

Comment: Hi Eraser. Good ideas! Any idea on how I do that in my OpenVPN conf?

Comment: A quick google search with "openvpn route internet traffic" will give you many answers, like [this one][1], for example

[1] http://www.wains.be/index.php/2008/07/18/openvpn-routing-all-traffic-through-the-vpn-tunnel/

Answer (score 1):

Eraser is correct with regards the 2 configuration setups. The control to change this is buried in the config panels of the Network Manager Open VPN setup (There is a checkbox with an option like "Use this connection for all routing" which, when unticked, will allow you to connect to the Internet through your normal connection and only use the VPN for IPs configured on the VPN network).

Alternatively, depending on the interface (not sure which type you're using), there should be a "Only use VPN for these addresses" checkbox with a text input to specify an IP range.

Comment: Can I set which programs may or may not route through the VPN?

Answer (score 0):

The network connection through the OpenVPN should work. Your case is an issue of getting more information and troubleshooting the problem.

Check the page https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VPNClient for tips.

Comment: Hi! I might be slightly off, but the page says "OpenVPN and IPSEC are not currently covered here." :)